# Merging/Bundling DLL/LIBs (C++/Java)

Tags: java, c++, dll

We currently use a software product which releases both dll and lib files for their software (they do not give us the source code).  Their files were written in C.  We write a dll wrapper for their software in C++ (using VS2010) and export all dlls to a java project.  We then load all the dlls in Java using System.loadLibrary() calls.  Everything works as expected.

The issue is that the software company will release a 'newer' version of the software (Ex v1.0, v2.5, etc), and the names of their dll's are identical even though the versions are different.  So we encounter errors in Java using the System.loadLibrary() calls because it doesn't know which one to reference (since they are all named the same).

I could see explicitly setting the VM args to point to a specific lib folder which contains the version we want (ex: -Djava.library.path=lib\v1_0).  The issue with that is we need to run ALL versions during the same java application (Ex: v1.0, v2.5, etc).

So my best guess is to try and bundle/merge the dlls so we only release 1 dll per version(containing our wrapper dll and all their dlls or libs), and that dll will be uniquely named.  Does anyone know how to do this or have a better way they can suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically load/unload dlls?  If so, this may serve as a solution.  So, if someone chooses 'V1.0' and runs the program it would somehow load the correct dll package, and then unload it after the run is complete.  Then someone could choose 'V2.5' and run the program and it would load that correct dll package and then unload it after the run is complete, etc...

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to remove the static references. They are intrinsically linked to the JNI static calls to static C code.   Could another workaround be to load each version of the software in different JVMs and talk back/forth to the correct ones?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven with the Maven NAR Plugin to manage the dependency hell.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm not sure that would work for this situation.  The Java application will be released to the client as an executable jar.  The main program will be a GUI which allows them to select which version of the software program they want to use when running the program.  So they may select V1.0, run the program, and after it completes they may then select v2.5, run the program and eventually close the GUI when done.

Comment: Well, you could bundle multiple versions and set up the library path dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following exactly...  by 'bundle multiple versions' do you mean create a different jar/gui for each software version?  If so, that wouldn't be possible due to other constraints outside the scope of this thread :(

Comment: Too bad. Maybe you have to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: I'm not sure what more to elaborate on.  In a nutshell I'm looking for a way to uniquely bundle a set of dlls for each version of the 3rd party software.  I will use all versions of these bundles at the same time within the java program.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think so. You can use only **one** at runtime unless you unload and reload.

Comment: Yes, please see my additional comments in the original post.  I am currently looking at dynamically loading/unloading.  I tried to follow the instructions here [link](http://codethesis.com/tutorial.php?id=1) but I am now encountering InvocationTargetException/UnsatisfiedLinkError errors, which I am currently looking into

Comment: Btw, I found out why I'm getting those errors.  The JNI wrapper class has all static methods and is therefore getting loaded by the default classloader.  The class that does the loadLibrary calls gets the custom classloader.  So I'll most likely have to muck with the JNI wrapper a bit so it gets loaded in the custom classloader